# Android sharedpreferences.getBoolean() returns the wrong, default value

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

[image]

On the picture you can see that the boolean variable took the default value, even though there was a key-value pair in the `SharedPreferences` with the right key. What can cause this? In the code this is at the end of an `onCreate` method. After this the `onMapReady` method gets called (from `com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback`), where I check the SAME boolean value, to see If i have to place some markers on the map or not. In that method the `getBoolean()` behaviour is correct, the default value is ignored. This doesn't make any sense to me, anyone can help me out?

Comment: Please show where you put that boolean into the same shared preferences

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) **Did you intend the space in the key "isThereReservation "  ?**  In your debug code, the variable doesn't have a space. Make sure you use the right key else you'll get the default value!

2) **How are you saving the sharedPref?** your code should be:

```
myPrefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
myPrefEditor = myPrefs.edit();
myPrefsEditor.clear();
myPrefsEditor.putBoolean("MY_KEY",myBool);
```

and then you can access by using:

```
myPrefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
myPrefs.getBoolean("MY_KEY",MY_DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

Comment: i feel so dumb, thank you... I looked at the code for spelling like 10 times and never noticed the space. I should delete this question then right? Cause it's probably not gonna help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

**The method getBoolean return default value if the key doesn't exist**. In your case, the **default value is false** and if the key of the SharedPreference doesn't exist is false in your case.

You are showing in debug the value of the HashMap **mMap** but  what is the content of the eu.arrowhed.arrowheaddemo for the same key?

Comment: prefs is a global variable in the activity, you can see the only initialization on the picture. that mMap hashmap belongs to the prefs variable.